# Link between deformation and velocity gradient: $L_v = \dot{M}_t \cdot M_t^{-1}$

Tags: mathematical-physics, fluid-dynamics

I'm studying fluid dynamics and I'm really struggling with notations and passages in some proofs that simply vanish.

In this question I need some guide-lines to show how to link the defomation map of a fluid and the velocity gradient: Let $B_0$ be a body that after a certain amount of time $t$ takes a different shape $B_t$. Supposing the change of shape is smooth enought into time, I used to call $M_t$ the deformation map which takes $B_0 \to B_t$.

Now, a part the clarifications about eulerian and lagrangian descripition of motion that is almost clear to me, I struggling to prove a theorem that states:
$$L_v = \dot{M}_t \cdot M_t^{-1}$$
where $L_v$ is used ad a notation of the gradient of velocity (which one: the eulero's or lagrange's one?) and the dot operator is the convective/material derivative.

Can anyone help me to dissolve my doubts and give me a sketch of proof (in the case the theorem I stated is true)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$M_t=\frac{\partial\mathbf{x}(t)}{\partial\mathbf{x}(0)}$, so
$$
\begin{split}
\dot{M}_t M_t^{-1} = \left[\frac{D}{\mathrm{d}t}\frac{\partial\mathbf{x}(t)}{\partial\mathbf{x}(0)}\right]\left[\frac{\partial\mathbf{x}(t)}{\partial\mathbf{x}(0)}\right]^{-1}\\
=\left[\frac{\partial\mathbf{v}(t)}{\partial\mathbf{x}(0)}\right]\cdot\left[\frac{\partial\mathbf{x}(0)}{\partial\mathbf{x}(t)}\right]=\frac{\partial\mathbf{v}(t)}{\partial\mathbf{x}(t)}=L_\mathbf{v}
\end{split}
$$
This is an Eulerian quantity because we are taking derivative with respect to the current $\mathbf{x}(t)$ not a fixed reference $\mathbf{x}(0)$.

Comment: I miss the passage $\left[\frac{D}{\mathrm{d}t}\frac{\partial\mathbf{x}(t)}{\partial\mathbf{x}(0)}\right]\left[\frac{\partial\mathbf{x}(t)}{\partial\mathbf{x}(0)}\right]^{-1}
=\left[\frac{\partial\mathbf{v}(t)}{\partial\mathbf{x}(0)}\right]\cdot\left[\frac{\partial\mathbf{x}(0)}{\partial\mathbf{x}(t)}\right]$. Can you be more specific please?

Comment: That is just $\frac{D}{\mathrm{d}t}\mathbf{x}(t)=\mathbf{v}(t)$ (since $\mathbf{x}(0)$ is fixed you can swap $\frac{\partial}{\partial\mathbf{x}(0)}$ and material derivative), and the chain rule to get $[\frac{\partial\mathbf{a}}{\partial\mathbf{b}}]^{-1}=\frac{\partial\mathbf{b}}{\partial\mathbf{a}}$.